# React-table sort custom rendered cells containing two values or symbols

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

In this case, I have two values in each cell (like rank and value) but I only want to sort on one of the two but setting sortBy doesn't work. I tried creating a custom function using sortMethod, but I have no idea how it works like if I did something like that.  (I just copy-pasted the function from some other response to see if I could get anything to even print)

```
sortMethod: (a, b) => {
     console.log(a,b)
     if (a.length === b.length) {
        return a > b ? 1 : -1;
       }
     return a.length > b.length ? 1 : -1;
  }
```

I have no idea what a and b are or how to reference them for my situation and I can't even get a and b to print to the console when I click which makes me think that I'm doing something so wrong that the function's not even triggering.

Also to render the cell, I couldn't figure out how to just add a value without adding a wrapped div, so it looks like this because I need two different styles for the two values

```
Cell: ({ row: { original } }) => (<div className = 'pctl' data-rk={original.percentile}>
      {original.percentile}
     <span className='stat'> {original.value}</span>
</div>),
```

Comment: the sorting functionality sorts via the 'accessor' value you pass to the columns.  The 'Cell' property lets you over ride what you display.  If you want to sort by a specific value make sure that values key is specified in the accessor property in columns.

Comment: Ah that explains so much.  got it working easily now.  not sure how to mark a comment as the right answer, but thank you so much!